# Is it correct that if S is the transitive closure of R and (x, y) is in S but not in R, then there is a z such that (x, z) is in R and (z, y) is in R?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Is the following correct? If so, how can it be proven? If not, what's a counterexample?

Let $S$ be the transitive closure of a relation $R \subseteq A \times A$. Suppose $(x, y) \in S$ and $(x, y) \notin R$. Then $\exists z \in A((x, z) \in R \land (z, y) \in R)$.

Comment: It is false. I recommend writing out some examples. You can, if you find it useful, easily visualize a relation as a graph and the transitive closure will then correspond to vertices connected by a path.

Comment: Note that transitive closure of $R$ is $S = \displaystyle \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} R^n$ while your claim is equivalent to $S = R \cup R^2$.

Comment: Thank you for your responses.

Comment: It is illegal and presumably rare for someone's great-grandparent also to be their grandparent! (It would make one heck of a family tree.)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the relation $R = \{(n, n+1): n \in \mathbb{N}\}$.

Then the transitive closure is $S= \{(n,m): n < m, n,m \in \mathbb{N}\}$. We need $m-n$ steps in $R$ to get to $(n,m) \in S$, so
now consider $(0,3) \in S\setminus R$, e.g.